# Wordpress is adding hidden <p> to html. How do I delete them?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have got extra space showing up in between divs (within a man div) that appears to be caused by random `<p>` and `</p>` being added by wordpress. I know this happens a lot with WP, but these ones are hidden, meaning I cannot access them from the HTML tab.

The code I have inserted looks like this:

```
<div class="classname">Text Example
<div class="classname-2">Input box text: <input style="width:100px;' text-align:center;" type="text" size="30" maxlength="20" /></div>
</div>
```

However, when I view the source code from the live site, it looks like this:

```
<div class="classname">Text Example</p>
<div class="classname-2">Input box text: <input style="width:100px;' text-align:center;" type="text" size="30" maxlength="20" /></div>
</div>
```

There is a `</p>` tag randomly inserted behind "Text Example." The code continues, and there is another arbitrary `<p>` inserted later.

Anyway to get rid of these? They do not show in the HTML tab.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that's how these editors handle new blocks. What I do is clean it with PHP prior to saving the file, but I think you can just backspace/delete around the areas. Very annoying that they do that. (You can access the source code after editing to clean it up as well. not ideal but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured out a little bootleg way to hide these `<p>` tags within the `<div>` in question:

Added to style.css:

```
.classname p {display: none;}
```

Since the `<p>` is inaccessible from the HTML tab, this at least makes them not display. It works well in this situation because I just needed it for this specific `<div>` but its probably not the best long-term solution if you are constantly running into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

- **Solution 1:**
  Add this to your functions.php in your current template folder to disable the automatic paragraph creation globally:

  > remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
- **Solution 2**:
  Install a plugin. I usually go with [raw html](http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/).
  It adds shortcode capability which can be useful and adds meta box to disable automatic paragraph creation manually on every post/page.
- **Solution 3**: remove the line breaks where the paragraphs appear:

  > `<div class="classname">Text Example<div class="classname-2">Input box text: <input style="width:100px;' text-align:center;" type="text" size="30" maxlength="20" /></div></div>`
  >   But that messes up your code visually...

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin: http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/disable-wpautop/

`<p>` tags get removed

Or

Adding this code at the top of your templates pages:

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop